# How do I add a bitmap image to a PDF in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, bitmap

I am building an Android app that enables users to add their digital signature to PDF files. What I did so far is that user can browse and choose a PDF file to view it by this function:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                    FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

In the `onActivityResult` method I throw the chosen file URI to PDF viewer to view it. Then the user can add their signature by custom view and I get the signature as bitmap and save it as an image to the local device storage.

What I want is to add this image to the current viewed PDF file to be part of it and save the PDF file again with the image.

Does any one know how to add the signature bitmap image to the PDF file and save it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the country your app is being used in, I would advise you to be very careful with the term "digital signature".

Just adding the image of somebody's signature is not a very secure strategy. Using Adobe, it is very easy to extract images. That means I could "fake" the signature of any signed document I have by simply re-inserting the image.

In a more sophisticated approach, the signature is made by adding extra information to the file as follows (simplified):

- Bob wants to sign a pdf document
- Bob calculates the hash value of the PDF (for instance using SHA256)
- Bob encrypts this hash-value using his private key
- Bob adds the encrypted hash-value to the document (alongside his public key, the regular hash value, the names of the algorithms involved and a timestamp)

Suppose now that Alice wants to verify whether Bob has signed

- Alice knows the algorithm Bob used to hash the document
- Alice decrypts the encrypted hash (we call this a signed hash) using Bob's public key
- the decrypted hash value should equal the regular hash value of the document
- using a Certificate Authority, Alice knows that the public key being used indeed belongs to Bob

Why does this work?

- Integrity : If anyone changes anything in the document, the hash would change. And Bob's signed hash would no longer match the hash of the document. So Bob's signature can only be valid as long as the document is not changed
- Non repudiation : Only Bob is supposed to have Bob's private key. Only Bob can sign the hash value. Bob can not deny having signed a document.
- Authentication : Alice knows (because of the CA) that it is indeed Bob that signed the document.

There's a cool ebook about this
http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html

Comment: very interesting ! thanks for clarification